# R - search one string for values in another string, values in each string not in same order

Tags: r

I looked around for this for awhile, a few online resources got close but none did exactly what I need.

I have two datasets, dataset1 has a field 'Name' that is a first and last name, dataset2 has a field 'Filename' that is the filename of a pdf/docx file. The values in dataset1 are always in order of first/last and always separated by a single space - 'Jimbo Jones.' The values in dataset2 could be in any order and don't always have a space between them.

I need to take the values from dataset1 and compare them to the values in dataset2, and return the filename from dataset2 associated with each name in dataset1.

Example data are below, as well as an ideal outcome.

Tidyverse solutions are preferred but I'll take what I can get.

Thank you in advance.

```
eg_data1 <- tibble(
  Name = c('Jeff Mills', 'Mike Banks', 'Mark Ernestus', 'Woody McBride', 'Adam Beyer', 'Cari Lekebusch'))
eg_data2 <- tibble(
  FileName = c('Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Jeff Mills.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Banks_Mike_history.doc', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Mark_Ernestus_bio_2021.08.13.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Woody McBride yeah.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Beyer_Adam_Beyer.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Cari Lekebusch docs.pdf'))
eg_data3 <- tibble(
  Name = c('Jeff Mills', 'Mike Banks', 'Mark Ernestus', 'Woody McBride', 'Adam Beyer', 'Cari Lekebusch'),
    FileName = c('Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Jeff Mills.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Banks_Mike_history.doc', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Mark_Ernestus_bio_2021.08.13.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Woody McBride yeah.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Beyer_Adam_Beyer.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Cari Lekebusch docs.pdf'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for this type of question really depends on how complicated your actual use-case is, but one option is to use the fuzzyjoin package (https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

eg_data1 <- tibble(
  Name = c('Jeff Mills', 'Mike Banks', 'Mark Ernestus', 'Woody McBride', 'Adam Beyer', 'Cari Lekebusch'))
eg_data2 <- tibble(
  FileName = c('Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Jeff Mills.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Banks_Mike_history.doc', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Mark_Ernestus_bio_2021.08.13.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Woody McBride yeah.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Beyer_Adam_Beyer.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Cari Lekebusch docs.pdf'))
eg_data3 <- tibble(
  Name = c('Jeff Mills', 'Mike Banks', 'Mark Ernestus', 'Woody McBride', 'Adam Beyer', 'Cari Lekebusch'),
  FileName = c('Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Jeff Mills.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Banks_Mike_history.doc', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Mark_Ernestus_bio_2021.08.13.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Woody McBride yeah.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Beyer_Adam_Beyer.pdf', 'Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Cari Lekebusch docs.pdf'))

eg_data1 %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(eg_data2, by = c("Name" = "FileName"), 
                  match_fun = function(x, y){str_detect(y, str_split(x, " ", simplify = TRUE))})
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   Name           FileName                                                     
#>   <chr>          <chr>                                                        
#> 1 Jeff Mills     Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Jeff Mills.pdf                  
#> 2 Mike Banks     Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Banks_Mike_history.doc          
#> 3 Mark Ernestus  Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Mark_Ernestus_bio_2021.08.13.pdf
#> 4 Woody McBride  Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Woody McBride yeah.pdf          
#> 5 Adam Beyer     Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Beyer_Adam_Beyer.pdf            
#> 6 Cari Lekebusch Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Cari Lekebusch docs.pdf
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-09 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

NB. If this doesn't work with your actual data, please update your question and I'll try changing the `match_fun` to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve the task. As @jared_mamrot already provided my favorite solution, this one is only for special cases. The idea is to breakdown each Name to a combination of strings and reverse strings and the match them by partial matching with `regex_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin` package:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

eg_data2 %>% 
  mutate(string = str_extract(FileName, "[^/]+(?=\\.)"),
           string = tolower(gsub(" |_", "", string))
           ) %>% 
  regex_left_join(eg_data1 %>% 
                    mutate(reverse = paste(word(Name, 2), word(Name, 1))) %>% 
                    rowwise() %>% 
                    mutate(across(everything(), ~ tolower(gsub(" ", "", .)), .names = "string_{.col}")) %>% 
                    unite(string, c(string_Name, string_reverse), sep = "|", remove = FALSE), 
                  by = "string") %>% 
  select(Name, FileName)
```

```
  Name           FileName                                                     
  <chr>          <chr>                                                        
1 Jeff Mills     Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Jeff Mills.pdf                  
2 Mike Banks     Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Banks_Mike_history.doc          
3 Mark Ernestus  Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Mark_Ernestus_bio_2021.08.13.pdf
4 Woody McBride  Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Woody McBride yeah.pdf          
5 Adam Beyer     Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Beyer_Adam_Beyer.pdf            
6 Cari Lekebusch Y:/MyStuff/NoReally/Mine/Bio/Cari Lekebusch docs.pdf
```